# SharePoint 2010 "Table of contents" web part showing deleted site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I made a test site, based on a template, named "test", and deleted it. However, the TOC web part on http://projects.company.tld/innovation/SitePages/Home.aspx still shows the "test" entry.

I think it's the opposite of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6b6rFKI3eU&feature=youtu.be&t=15s), except i can't find that "Delete Enterprise Objects" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alot of items in SharePoint are cached for increased performance.  You get the similar issue with the CQWP (Content Query WebPart) caching for performance.

Answer (score 0):

It just disappeared. Probably a cache issue.